# How can i give style to the ul inside the pagination

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to give style to the `ul` inside the `Pagination`, but no matter what i do nothing works!
Here is a picture:
[image]
As you can see i want to give the style to `MuiPagination-ul` class
Here is what i tried so far :

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    Pagination: {
        root: {
            MuiPagination: {
                ul: {
                    display: 'inline-flex'
                }
            }   
        }            
    }
}));  

<Pagination className={classes.Pagination}/>
```

I also tried it without it being inside a root, and also using a string like

```
'MuiPagination-ul': {display: 'inline-flex'}
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find using `withStyles` to be the simplest way to customize a Material-UI component. You can look at how the [default Pagination styles](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.12/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Pagination/Pagination.js#L12) are defined in order to see the syntax to use.

Below is a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Pagination from "@material-ui/lab/Pagination";

const StyledPagination = withStyles({
  ul: {
    display: "inline-flex"
  }
})(Pagination);

export default function BasicPagination() {
  return <StyledPagination count={10} color="primary" />;
}
```

[image: Edit Pagination ul]

If you use `makeStyles/useStyles` you can only use the `className` prop if you are customizing the `root` CSS class, but in your case you need to customize the `ul` CSS class (which is [applied to a different element](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.12/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Pagination/Pagination.js#L62) than the [root CSS class](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.12/packages/material-ui-lab/src/Pagination/Pagination.js#L58). This requires using the `classes` prop and specifying the `ul` property within it.

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Pagination from "@material-ui/lab/Pagination";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  ul: {
    display: "inline-flex"
  }
});

export default function BasicPagination() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Pagination count={10} color="primary" classes={classes}/>;
}
```

[image: Edit Pagination ul]

If your `makeStyles` call includes additional classes that aren't intended for `Pagination`, then you can be more explicit about what you put in the `classes` prop:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Pagination from "@material-ui/lab/Pagination";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  paginationUL: {
    display: "inline-flex"
  }
});

export default function BasicPagination() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Pagination
      count={10}
      color="primary"
      classes={{ ul: classes.paginationUL }}
    />
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Pagination ul]